# What do the outputs of my zero inflated poisson model mean? (counts of fish)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation, poisson-distribution, biostatistics, zero-inflation

I am looking a counts of fish within different size classes (0-10, 10-20 etc) between 3 different reef sites, 3 different depths and 2 different survey methods. However, naturally on all observations I did not identify fish to fit all size classes and hence my data has a lot of zeros and is counts.

Because of this I assumed I would need to use a ZIP GLM so I compared the fit of a GLM with a regular Poisson distribution and a ZIP Poisson GLM as well:

```r
    model1 <- 
    glm(vs ~ method+site+depth, data=length.dat, family="poisson")
    model2 <- 
    zeroinfl(vs ~ method+site+depth, data=length.dat, dist="poisson")
    vuong(model1, model2)
```

I then compared the fit of the two models using the Vuong test and results showed that a ZIP model was most appropriate.

I then ran the model for one of my response variables the size class 'very small' and this was the output:

```r
    Pearson residuals:
           Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
    -8.276e-01 -1.814e-01 -1.615e-03 -6.804e-06  3.727e+00 
    
    Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
    (Intercept)   3.3414   106.4449   0.031  0.97496   
    method.L     -1.5128     0.4864  -3.110  0.00187 **
    site.L       -8.4777   225.7975  -0.038  0.97005   
    site.Q       -7.7973   130.3643  -0.060  0.95231   
    depth.L      -8.8354   225.7980  -0.039  0.96879   
    depth.Q      -3.9120   130.3721  -0.030  0.97606   
    
    Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
    (Intercept)   4.2989    34.3016   0.125    0.900
    method.L      0.8108     1.1095   0.731    0.465
    site.L       -9.4201    72.9885  -0.129    0.897
    site.Q      -14.6625   110.7111  -0.132    0.895
    depth.L     -16.8747   114.8328  -0.147    0.883
    depth.Q      -8.5142    66.4256  -0.128    0.898
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

From what I understand, zero inflated models treat the data as two sets. One that is all zeros and one that is zeros and counts is that correct? I think this is telling me that fish within this size class are significantly different between the sampling methods but I am unsure and what does it mean if there is a significant result in the zero inflated Poisson in comparison to the zero inflated binomial?

Also do I need to check for overdispersion with a ZIP model and is the analysis over, I have seen some people using chi2?